# What computers are participating in ROS right now?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having gotten through a particularly annoying troubleshooting session, I think there must be a tool that would have helped me. Along the lines of rosnode and rostopic, I would like to see a listing of what the computers are that are participating, e.g.

```
computer-a (ip 12.1.2.3, ubuntu 16.04)
  Node one
     Topic X (published)
     Topic Y (published)
 - Node two
     Topic H (subscribed)
compute-b  (ip 12.1.2.4, ubuntu 16.04)
  - Node three
      Topic X (subscribed)
```

Note specifically the mention of distinct "computers" so that one could tell that topic Y had no subscribers. I am not sure to be honest whether this would have smoked out by config problem but it would seem that something more would have been useful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298845/what-computers-are-participating-in-ros-right-now?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you're looking for this:

```
rostopic list --host
```

Adding `-v` gives you something like:

```
Host [some_hostname]:

  Published topics:
   * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher

  Subscribed topics:
   * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
Note btw that this is technically not an actual answer to your question: `rostopic list` will only show the topics registered with a master (and the hostnames/nodes). There can be multiple masters, so this is not an exhaustive list.

"participating in ROS" is also an ambiguous question.